# Cinch doesn't work | How do I enable access to assistive devices in OS X 10.9 Mavericks?

Tags: mac, macos, software-update, software

Cinch requires us to "Enable access to assistive devices". However this option is not found on OS X Mavericks > System Preferences. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy > Accessibility > "Click the lock to make changes" > Select "Cinch" 
[image]